# Div sections in same line

Tags: html, css

I need to have the below two div to be remain in the same line(like tables) even after resizing the window to minimum size.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="">
    <div id="div1" style="display:inline-block;">
        <p>this is div one. this should remain in  same line with div 2 even after resizing the window.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" style="display:inline-block">
        <p>this is div two. this should remain in  same line with div 1 even after resizing the window.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` to wrapper, and it will do the job

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="display:flex">
<div id="div1">

<p>this is div one. this should remain in  same line with div 2 even after resizing the window.</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<p>this is div two. this should remain in  same line with div 1 even after resizing the window.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current setup just add width to you div's. That will get the div's next to each other.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1" style="width:50%; display:inline-block;">
        <p>this is div one. this should remain in  same line with div 2 even after resizing the window.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" style="width:50%; display:inline-block">
        <p>this is div two. this should remain in  same line with div 1 even after resizing the window.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It would be preferable to use CSS classes instead of inline CSS.
Also there is `CSS flexbox` that you can use.